# Issue closing wxpython frame from other module

Tags: wxpython

I'm making a simple contact compiler that currently uses three modules: one for the person class that takes in information, one for the newContact Frame class that allows the user to submit information, and one for the front page Frame class that lists the names of contacts and gives users options to edit the list.

The issue I'm having is when I call the main function of the newContact class inside the front page class, it doesn't exit the MainLoop. Even though I destroyed the newContact window and both programs close normally when not called from eachother. Here's the relevant code:

```
import wx
import person

contacts = []
names = []

class newContact(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newContact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.basicWindow()
        self.Show()

    def basicWindow(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vertical = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


        heading = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Create New Contact')
        vertical.Add(heading, flag = wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border = 5)

        nameBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        nameText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Name:')
        nameBox.Add(nameText)
        self.nameEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        nameBox.Add(self.nameEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 50)
        vertical.Add(nameBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        phoneBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        phoneText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Number:')
        phoneBox.Add(phoneText)
        self.phoneEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        phoneBox.Add(self.phoneEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 38)
        vertical.Add(phoneBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        mailBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mailText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Email:')
        mailBox.Add(mailText)
        self.mailEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        mailBox.Add(self.mailEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 53)
        vertical.Add(mailBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        submit = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Submit', size = (70,30))
        vertical.Add(submit, flag = wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.registerData)

        panel.SetSizer(vertical)


    def registerData(self, e):
        name = self.nameEntry.GetValue()
        name = name.title()
        while True:
            try:
                number = int(self.phoneEntry.GetValue())
                break
            except ValueError:
                number = 'a'
                break
        email = self.mailEntry.GetValue()

        contact = person.Person(name, number, email)
        names.append(name)
        contacts.append(contact)

        print('hello')

        self.quit()

    def quit(self):
        self.Destroy()


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    newContact(None, title = 'New Contact', size = (405, 200), style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

```
import wx
import newContact

class Front(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Front, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.interaction()

    def interaction(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        wholeGrid = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label = '  Contact List')
        wholeGrid.Add(title, flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        self.contactList = wx.ListBox(panel)
        mainBox.Add(self.contactList, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border = 10)

        buttonList = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        new = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_NEW, label = 'New', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(new)
        edit = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_EDIT, label = 'Edit', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(edit, flag = wx.TOP, border = 5)
        delete = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_DELETE, label = 'Delete', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(delete, flag = wx.TOP, border = 5)
        mainBox.Add(buttonList, flag = wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

        wholeGrid.Add(mainBox, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)

        panel.SetSizer(wholeGrid)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.createNew, id = wx.ID_NEW)


        menu = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit')
        menu.Append(fileMenu, 'File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu)

        self.Show(True)

    def createNew(self, e):
        newContact.main()



def main():
    app = wx.App()
    Front(None, title = "Contacts", size = (405,600), style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for any help, code syntax commentary will also be appreciated.

Comment: Striped out to bare minimum code that is runnable and represents the problem your getting would be easier to respond to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're just closing the newContact frame, not the top level Front frame. You should be able to do something like this in your newContact's quit method:

```
import wx

class newContact(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newContact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.basicWindow()
        self.Show()

    def basicWindow(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vertical = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


        heading = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Create New Contact')
        vertical.Add(heading, flag = wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border = 5)

        nameBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        nameText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Name:')
        nameBox.Add(nameText)
        self.nameEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        nameBox.Add(self.nameEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 50)
        vertical.Add(nameBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        phoneBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        phoneText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Number:')
        phoneBox.Add(phoneText)
        self.phoneEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        phoneBox.Add(self.phoneEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 38)
        vertical.Add(phoneBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        mailBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mailText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Email:')
        mailBox.Add(mailText)
        self.mailEntry = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        mailBox.Add(self.mailEntry, proportion = 1, flag = wx.LEFT, border = 53)
        vertical.Add(mailBox, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        submit = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Submit', size = (70,30))
        vertical.Add(submit, flag = wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.registerData)

        panel.SetSizer(vertical)


    def registerData(self, e):
        #name = self.nameEntry.GetValue()
        #name = name.title()
        #while True:
            #try:
                #number = int(self.phoneEntry.GetValue())
                #break
            #except ValueError:
                #number = 'a'
                #break
        #email = self.mailEntry.GetValue()

        #contact = person.Person(name, number, email)
        #names.append(name)
        #contacts.append(contact)

        self.quit()

    def quit(self):
        parent = self.GetParent()
        parent.Close()


class Front(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Front, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.interaction()

    def interaction(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        wholeGrid = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label = '  Contact List')
        wholeGrid.Add(title, flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border = 10)

        self.contactList = wx.ListBox(panel)
        mainBox.Add(self.contactList, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border = 10)

        buttonList = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        new = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_NEW, label = 'New', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(new)
        edit = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_EDIT, label = 'Edit', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(edit, flag = wx.TOP, border = 5)
        delete = wx.Button(panel, id = wx.ID_DELETE, label = 'Delete', size = (100,30))
        buttonList.Add(delete, flag = wx.TOP, border = 5)
        mainBox.Add(buttonList, flag = wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

        wholeGrid.Add(mainBox, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)

        panel.SetSizer(wholeGrid)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.createNew, id = wx.ID_NEW)


        menu = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit')
        menu.Append(fileMenu, 'File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu)

        self.Show(True)

    def createNew(self, e):
        other_frame = newContact(self)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App() 
    Front(None, title = "Contacts", 
          size = (405,600), style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION) 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Changed the code slightly to make it run without saving two files. You are not supposed to call a class directly as you were doing in the **createNew** method, so I changed that...also note that there is no **main** method anyway.

Comment: This got the frame out of its MainLoop, but it sent an error asking for an arg(win) in GetTopLevelParent. What argument is this?

Comment: Added a destroy function to quit. The issue was as you said, calling a main loop inside another. Thanks.